# PowerShell: search for a file path in the top level of a folder; warn the user if it's not found and proceed to search recursively

Tags: command-line, powershell

I am writing an auto-grading script that warns the user if the student has/has not followed the directory requirements: specifically, a *single* file, `main.cpp` in a folder, named appropriately. If that file is not found in the top level, warn the user, but continue to recursively look for the file in any subdirectory. If no file is found, send an error, but continue processing the rest of the directories in the parent directory.

This is my attempt so far, and it does not entirely work—the warning is sent even when the user has *no* `main.cpp` file at all, when I want only 3 possible outputs:

1. no warning, and continue to build;
2. file found recursively, but warning sent;
3. file not found and error, but continue processing the other folders.

How may I fix it?

```
function Copy-Files {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$CurrentDir,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$StudentNum
    )

    # Try to copy assignment files to the marking folder. Check error conditions and warn marker appropriately.
    try {
        $DoneFiles | ForEach-Object {
            Copy-Item -Force -Path "$CurrentDir\$_" -Destination .\marking -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    }
    catch {
        try {
            $DoneFiles | ForEach-Object {
                Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrentDir -File -Recurse -Filter "$_" | Copy-Item -Force -Destination .\marking -ErrorAction Stop
            }
            Write-Warning "$StudentNumber did not follow the specified folder convention, but all files were submitted."
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error -Message "$StudentNumber did not submit any of: $DoneFiles." -Category InvalidData
            Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "*_lab${Env:AssignNumber}" | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentFolder = $_
    $StudentNumber = $CurrentFolder.Name.Replace("_lab${Env:AssignNumber}", "")

    Copy-Files -CurrentDir $CurrentFolder -StudentNum $StudentNumber

    if ($AllFound -and $IsCMake) {
        Invoke-CMake -DoneFileNames $DoneFiles -IsFirstCompile $FirstCompile -StudentNum $StudentNumber
    }
    # Run VS Code with diff
    Compare-Code -DoneFileNames $DoneFiles -StudentNum $StudentNumber
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is an awkward behavior from `Copy-Item`. If you pass an empty/null collection through the pipeline (like from `Get-ChildItem`), it doesn't error out. Different than you may expect, since piping in `$null` does throw an error:

```
Get-ChildItem './MySrc' -Filter 'BadFilter' | Copy-Item ./MyDst  ## No Error
$Null | Copy-Item ./MyDst  ## Does Error
```

For files, I prefer a structure like `If (Test-Path){}` over `Try`/`Catch` in order to make sure paths and such are still valid before attempting changes:

```
# Check if file exists in correct path and copy,
If (Test-Path "$CurrentDir\$_") {
  Copy-Item -Force -Path "$CurrentDir\$_" -Destination .\marking
}

# Otherwise check recursively for the correct file and show a warning if found
ElseIf (Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrentDir -File -Recurse -Filter "$_") {
  Write-Warning "$StudentNumber did not follow the specified folder convention, but all files were submitted."
  Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrentDir -File -Recurse -Filter "$_" |
    Copy-Item -Force -Destination .\marking
}

# Error out if file not found
Else { 
  Write-Error -Message "$StudentNumber did not submit any of: $DoneFiles." -Category InvalidData
  Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
}
```